# SCP to transfer files from remote server which are modified after specific time

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ssh, scp

In remote server log files are rotated as shown below when the size of the active log file (file.log) is reached 100mb

```
delete file.log.4
file.log.3 -> file.log.4
file.log.2 -> file.log.3
file.log.1 -> file.log.2
file.log   -> file.log.1
```

Initially all the files will be moved to local server and renamed as below

```
file.log_timestamp_of_log4
file.log_timestamp_of_log3
file.log_timestamp_of_log2
file.log_timestamp_of_log1
```

Then after only those files which are modified after the last script run time should be moved to local server. 
for example next time when the script runs if file.log.1 and file.log.2 has modification time greater than the previous script rum time   then only these should be moved to local server.

Can this be done using scp ?

Comment: `rsync` is better at handling your case.

Answer (score 0):

scp is command to copy from one server to other. So if you are copying from remote to local **yes you can use scp**. To fetch previous modified date you can use `date -r` . You can save last script run time to compare. You need to use `scp -p`  to preserve modifed date. To calculate size you can use `du -h`
So do something like following algo

```
scp -p remotepath:/filename localpath

last_mod = date -r filename

size = du -h filename

if last_mod > script_runtime
{ if size > 100 MB 
 { mv filename > filename1 }
}
```